# How to produce a sound in Android with a loudness in decibel instead of a percentage?

Tags: android, audio

For Android smartphones, is it possible to set the loudness in decibel for the headphone jack or internal speaker instead of using the percentage Loudness?

I want to produce a sound which loudness is the exact same across all smartphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Differing sensitivities of headphones would make this impossible, even if you could standardise the voltage at the headphone jack.